# Doctrine DBAL join without ON clause

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

**In plain SQL I would do this**

```
select t1.id, t2.id from table1 t1 join table2 t2;
```

**Ho would you achieve same using doctrine dbal querybuilder**

```
$qb = $this->_em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()

$qb->select('t1.id, t2.id')
   ->from('table1','t1')
   ->join('t1', 'table2', 't2') //without on clause, this doesn't work
   ->execute()
   ->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$qb->select('t1.id', 't2.id')
   ->from('table1','t1')
   ->join('t1', 'table2', 't2', true)
   ->execute()
   ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Doesn't work it adds on clause at the end without condition which results in syntax error, Have tried it already

Comment: You are right, just add true condition :) I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

JOIN without "ON" expression is also known as CROSS JOIN.
According to documentation u can not do that with query builder

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#join-clauses

Only INNER, LEFT, RIGHT.

U just need a native query:

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();

$statement = $connection->prepare("
    select t1.id, t2.id from table1 t1 join table2 t2
");

$statement->execute();

$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

or to think a little bit more about what really you want to recieve